# me pueden ayudar a solucionar un error cuando quiero enviar un mensaje de correo en laravel?

Tags: php, html5, laravel

Cuando envio el correo me muestra este error:

> Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required
>   "

ya tengo configurado env. y el mail.php, estoy usando laravel 5.4

Comment: Al parecer podria ser los credenciales que utilizas para enviar el email

Comment: Que servicio de correo estas configurando en el `.env`? Podrías mostrar como tienes configurada la sección de Mail en el `.env` (ocultando los datos sensibles user y pass). También podrías probar ejecutando `php artisan config: cache` ya que sin este comando, laravel ejecuta la configuración previa de su caché.

Comment: estoy utilizando el de gmail y esto tengo en mi env. 
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

Answer (score 0):

Hola debes Verificar si estas utilizando correctamente el puerto y las credenciales. revisa esta documentación de gmail. y lo configuras en tu archivo .env

[Configuración de Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=es)

Comment: ya lo tengo configurado así pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: Trata de utilizar mailtrap para probar aqui te dejo un post que te podria ayudar [Como enviar email con mailtrap] (https://styde.net/como-enviar-emails-de-prueba-con-mailtrap-io-en-laravel/)